# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I got the encoding error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

at the following python (pyspark) code, where row is the data frame row:

```
def rowToLine(row):
  line = str(row[0]).strip()
  columnNum = 44
  for k in xrange(1, columnNum):
    line = line + "\t"
    line = line + str(row[k]).strip()  # encoding error here
  return line
```

---

I also tried the join below:

```
def rowToLine(row):
  s = "\t"
  return s.join(row)
```

but some values of the row is int, so I got errors:

```
TypeError: sequence item 19: expected string or Unicode, int found
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @Keven, I looked into the questioned you mentioned, but it is not clear to me how to convert row[k] to string without using str. Anything suggestions?

Comment: There is not enough context to say.  Do you want to output UTF-8?  ISO-8859-1?  Is your data even textual to begin with?

Comment: Side note: You want to be using [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).  It has better performance than the code you're using now.

Comment: Also, return "\t".join(str(cell).strip() for cell in row[:44]) can replace the entire function. (I think. Didn't try it.)

Comment: @Keven and user3757614: I tried join as well (see modified question above), but got errors as some value in the row is integer. Any suggestion? "UTF-8" would work. Thanks!

Comment: @user3757614: "\t".join(str(cell).strip()   I believe the str(cell) part will cause the encode error...

Comment: Well, the real question is what do you want it to return if there are unicode characters present? You can either return a unicode string, (which may break if you use it for other things) or you can strip out the unicode characters. (Which may break if you use it for other things.)

Comment: Don't call str on the unicode, encode the data with `row[k].encode("utf-8")` or just use the unicode, when you call str you are trying to encode to ascii which is obviously going to error for any non ascii characters, where is this data coming from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I did: "\t".join(x.encode("utf-8") for x in row)  however, I got the error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode' because some element in row is an int. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `"\t".join([ x.encode("utf-8")  if isinstance(x, basestring) else x  for x in row])`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham is the [ ] required ? I mean the [ ] enclose the  "x.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(x, basestring) else x for x in row". Thanks!

Comment: It is faster to use a list comp than a generator expression, a list is built regardless so there is no advantage to using a generator here at all

Comment: Is there a **good** reason for you not using Python 3 for this task?

Comment: I would need to convince the entire team and change the production system to python 3, which is not small task. Python 3 is a good idea, but would take sometime to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's suggestions!

I basically took Padraic Cunningham's idea and made some modification to handle the int case. The code below works.

```
def rowToLine(row):
  s = "\t"
  return s.join( x.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(x, basestring) else str(x).encode("utf-8") for x in row)
```